# How to send Next.js trace data to Datadog using OpentelemetryCollector

Tags: next.js, open-telemetry, datadog

I would like to send trace data from a Next.js application I am developing in TypeScript to Datadog, but I can't figure it out after reading the documentation and have not been able to do that.
I have specified Datadog as the exporter in collector.yaml and it shows graphs for CPU, memory, etc., but it does not show Traces data for GET and POST requests to the application.

Looking at the app log of the Docker container, it seems that traces are being made, but they are not being sent to Datadog.

How can I use OpentelemetryCollector to send application trace data to Datadog?

I am running in a local environment on a mac and don't know how to reference the logs in the Docker container, so I have commented out the filelog, is this the cause?

Here is what I have set up and the graph in question.

English may be unnatural due to the use of translation software. Sorry.

Translated with DeepL.com (free version)

・collector.yaml

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      http:
        endpoint: "localhost:4318"
      grpc:
        endpoint: "localhost:4317"
  hostmetrics:
    collection_interval: 10s
    scrapers:
      paging:
        metrics:
          system.paging.utilization:
            enabled: true
      cpu:
        metrics:
          system.cpu.utilization:
            enabled: true
      disk:
      filesystem:
        metrics:
          system.filesystem.utilization:
            enabled: true
      load:
      memory:
      network:
      processes:
  prometheus:
    config:
      scrape_configs:
      - job_name: 'otelcol'
        scrape_interval: 10s
        static_configs:
        - targets: ['0.0.0.0:8888']

  # filelog:
  #   include_file_path: true
  #   poll_interval: 500ms
  #   include:
  #     - /var/log/**/*example*/*.log

processors:
  batch:
    send_batch_max_size: 1000
    send_batch_size: 100
    timeout: 10s

exporters:
  datadog:
    api:
      site: datadoghq.com
      key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

service:
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [hostmetrics, prometheus, otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [datadog]
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [datadog]
    logs:
      # receivers: [otlp, filelog]
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [datadog]
```

・instrumentation.ts

```
/*instrumentation.ts*/
import { NodeSDK } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-node';
import { ConsoleSpanExporter } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node';
import { getNodeAutoInstrumentations } from '@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node';
import {
  PeriodicExportingMetricReader,
  ConsoleMetricExporter,
} from '@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics';

const sdk = new NodeSDK({
  traceExporter: new ConsoleSpanExporter(),
  metricReader: new PeriodicExportingMetricReader({
    exporter: new ConsoleMetricExporter(),
  }),
  instrumentations: [getNodeAutoInstrumentations()],
});

sdk.start();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DcT4.png)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the instrumentation is not actually exporting the data anywhere.

You are currently using `ConsoleSpanExporter` and `ConsoleMetricExporter` which exports Spans and Metrics to the console.

You need to change your instrumentation to use the `OTLP` exporters.

```js
import * as opentelemetry from '@opentelemetry/sdk-node';
import { getNodeAutoInstrumentations } from '@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node';
import { OTLPTraceExporter } from '@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-proto';
import { OTLPMetricExporter } from '@opentelemetry/exporter-metrics-otlp-proto';
import { PeriodicExportingMetricReader } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics';

const sdk = new opentelemetry.NodeSDK({
  traceExporter: new OTLPTraceExporter({
    // optional - default url is http://localhost:4318/v1/traces
    url: '<your-collector-endpoint>/v1/traces',
  }),
  metricReader: new PeriodicExportingMetricReader({
    exporter: new OTLPMetricExporter({
      // optional - default is http://localhost:4318/v1/metrics
      url: '<your-collector-endpoint>/v1/metrics',
    }),
  }),
  instrumentations: [getNodeAutoInstrumentations()],
});
sdk.start();
```

If your collector is exposing ports `4317` and `4318` to your localhost, you can remove the `url` from `OTLPTraceExporter` and `OTLPMetricExporter`.

If you prefer, you can also set the following environment variable in your application Dockerfile or Docker compose file to point the `OTLP` data to the collector:

```
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=http://<otel-collector-endpoint>:<otel-collector-port>
```

Another thing that I've noticed is that if you are using the OTel Collector version `0.95.0`+, you will also need the `datadog/connector` component in your collector config:

```yaml
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      http:
        endpoint: "localhost:4318"
      grpc:
        endpoint: "localhost:4317"
  hostmetrics:
    collection_interval: 10s
    scrapers:
      paging:
        metrics:
          system.paging.utilization:
            enabled: true
      cpu:
        metrics:
          system.cpu.utilization:
            enabled: true
      disk:
      filesystem:
        metrics:
          system.filesystem.utilization:
            enabled: true
      load:
      memory:
      network:
      processes:
  prometheus:
    config:
      scrape_configs:
      - job_name: 'otelcol'
        scrape_interval: 10s
        static_configs:
        - targets: ['0.0.0.0:8888']

  # filelog:
  #   include_file_path: true
  #   poll_interval: 500ms
  #   include:
  #     - /var/log/**/*example*/*.log

connectors:
    datadog/connector:

processors:
  batch:
    send_batch_max_size: 1000
    send_batch_size: 100
    timeout: 10s

exporters:
  datadog:
    api:
      site: datadoghq.com
      key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

service:
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [hostmetrics, prometheus, otlp, datadog/connector]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [datadog]
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [datadog, datadog/connector]
    logs:
      # receivers: [otlp, filelog]
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [datadog]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
The trace data remained hidden even after modifying it as you suggested.
I am now contacting Datadog support to try to resolve the issue.
I will post again here if I can resolve the issue.

Comment: Keiji, could you check if the traces are even being exported?
You can use the `debug` exporter to see if the Collector is exporting traces/metrics/logs.

Comment: I am sorry for the delay in replying as I have been ill in bed.
Sorry.
Actually, I changed the receiver URL from the default localhost to opentelemetry-collector and the trace data was displayed!
I didn't understand that we need to communicate between docker containers.
Thanks again and again for your advice.
I hope to learn and be able to advise someone like you.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the receiver URL from the default localhost to opentelemetry-collector and changed the endpoint to the following and the trace data is displayed!

・collector.yaml

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      http:
        endpoint: "0.0.0.0:4318"
      grpc:
        endpoint: "0.0.0.0:4317"
  hostmetrics:
    collection_interval: 10s
    scrapers:
      paging:
        metrics:
          system.paging.utilization:
            enabled: true
      cpu:
        metrics:
          system.cpu.utilization:
            enabled: true
      disk:
      filesystem:
        metrics:
          system.filesystem.utilization:
            enabled: true
      load:
      memory:
      network:
      processes:
  prometheus:
    config:
      scrape_configs:
      - job_name: 'otelcol'
        scrape_interval: 10s
        static_configs:
        - targets: ['0.0.0.0:8888']

  # filelog:
  #   include_file_path: true
  #   poll_interval: 500ms
  #   include:
  #     - /var/log/**/*example*/*.log

processors:
  batch:
    send_batch_max_size: 1000
    send_batch_size: 100
    timeout: 10s

exporters:
  datadog:
    api:
      site: datadoghq.com
      key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

service:
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [hostmetrics, prometheus, otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [datadog]
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [datadog]
    logs:
      # receivers: [otlp, filelog]
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [datadog]
```

・instrumentation.ts

```
import * as opentelemetry from '@opentelemetry/sdk-node';
import { getNodeAutoInstrumentations } from '@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node';
import { OTLPTraceExporter } from '@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-proto';
import { OTLPMetricExporter } from '@opentelemetry/exporter-metrics-otlp-proto';
import { PeriodicExportingMetricReader } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics';

const sdk = new opentelemetry.NodeSDK({
  traceExporter: new OTLPTraceExporter({
    url: 'http://opentelemetry-collector:4318/v1/traces',
  }),
  metricReader: new PeriodicExportingMetricReader({
    exporter: new OTLPMetricExporter({
      url: 'http://opentelemetry-collector:4318/v1/metrics',
    }),
  }),
  instrumentations: [getNodeAutoInstrumentations()],
});
sdk.start();
```